# Is it possible to shuffle the order of arrays in a .npz file?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a array of arrays which I save to a .npz file using

```
np.savez('test2.npz', *NumpyArrayOfArrays)
```

I was wondering if it's possible to shuffle the order in which the arrays are saved.

I tried

np.random.shuffle(testing)

Doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried plain old `random.shuffle()`?

```
import random
np.savez('test2.npz', *random.shuffle(NumpyArrayOfArrays))
```

Comment: Thanks, will be very useful for me, but I need something that can shuffle the npz file itself, since I need to do it several times through. What I could do is save several versions of shuffled data, but ultimately I'll need something that can shuffle it whenever needed.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by shuffling the file.  The `npz` file is a `zip` archive.  How or why does the order matter?

Comment: @SantoshGupta7 Right, so just shuffle the data while loading?

Answer (score 0):

If I start with a (4,3) array:

```
In [92]: arr
Out[92]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

And save it as you do, `*arr` treats it as a list of 1d arrays (rows), saving each to a separate file in `npz` archive:

```
In [93]: np.savez('test.npz', *arr)
```

`load` gives me a dictionary of these arrays:

```
In [94]: d = np.load('test.npz')
In [96]: list(d.keys())
Out[96]: ['arr_0', 'arr_1', 'arr_2', 'arr_3']
In [97]: d['arr_1']
Out[97]: array([3, 4, 5])
```

Or using the OS `unzip` to list the archive:

```
In [101]: !unzip -v test.npz
Archive:  test.npz
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
     152  Stored      152   0% 1980-01-01 00:00 ea1240f7  arr_0.npy
     152  Stored      152   0% 1980-01-01 00:00 c2903dd0  arr_1.npy
     152  Stored      152   0% 1980-01-01 00:00 987e678b  arr_2.npy
     152  Stored      152   0% 1980-01-01 00:00 fcae29f8  arr_3.npy
--------          -------  ---                            -------
     608              608   0%                            4 files
```

Apart from the names, the 'saving order' doesn't really matter.  Or at least I don't see why you care.

Alternatively I could set the archive file names with the dictionary approach

```
In [114]: names = ['w','x','y','z']
In [115]: dd = {n:v for n,v in zip(names,arr)}
In [116]: dd
Out[116]: 
{'w': array([0, 1, 2]),
 'x': array([3, 4, 5]),
 'y': array([6, 7, 8]),
 'z': array([ 9, 10, 11])}
In [117]: np.savez('test.npz', **dd)
In [118]: d = np.load('test.npz')
In [119]: list(d.keys())
Out[119]: ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
In [120]: d['x']
Out[120]: array([3, 4, 5])

In [121]: !unzip -v test.npz
Archive:  test.npz
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
     152  Stored      152   0% 1980-01-01 00:00 ea1240f7  w.npy
     152  Stored      152   0% 1980-01-01 00:00 c2903dd0  x.npy
     152  Stored      152   0% 1980-01-01 00:00 987e678b  y.npy
     152  Stored      152   0% 1980-01-01 00:00 fcae29f8  z.npy
--------          -------  ---                            -------
     608              608   0%                            4 files
```

I can use dictionary like methods to fetch values from the archive:

```
In [122]: list(d.items())
Out[122]: 
[('w', array([0, 1, 2])),
 ('x', array([3, 4, 5])),
 ('y', array([6, 7, 8])),
 ('z', array([ 9, 10, 11]))]
In [123]: list(d.values())
Out[123]: [array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([6, 7, 8]), array([ 9, 10, 11])]
In [124]: np.stack(_)
Out[124]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```